# How efficient is `slot-scope` over `v-for`?

Tags: vue.js, scope

How efficient is `slot-scope` over `v-for` ?

#### Isn't that the both are used for the straight similar purpose?

please correct this if i'm wrong.

Comment: I don't see how either are related. `slot-scope` is used for creating a new namespace to be used inside a slot, whereas `v-for` is for looping...I fail to see what you are actually asking here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`slot-scopes` and `slots` in general are totally different to `v-for`.

`v-for` is used to create a loop bound to a collection.

`slot` is used to pass DOM elements/data to a component.

`slot-scope` is used to pass component data to the underlying components - here's an example:

```
<json-get url="/api/v1/users">
    <template slot-scope="data">
        <ul>
            <li v-for="user in data.results">{{ user.name }}</li>
        </ul>
    </template>
</json-get>
```

`slot-scope="data"` passes info contained within 'data' for use of the nested DOM elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation.